# Are there fewer professional heavyweight boxers today than there were in the Golden Age of boxing in the 1970s?

Tags: boxing

I've often heard that today there are far fewer professional heavyweight boxers than there were in the 1970s, particularly due to more lucrative opportunities in other sports, and the long-term health risks of boxing as evidenced by figures like Muhammad Ali.

It's a claim I often see when people are claiming professional heavyweights of today to be far less capable than the golden age boxers.

I wouldn't have thought this to be true, as the global population is much bigger. Is there any truth to this claim?

Comment: Professional or just famous? I know of several boxers fighting professional (one even personally) who are known in their home region only.

Comment: @dly professional

Comment: Surely there cannot be less unless the weight categories have changed.  Or do you mean to say 'fewer'?

Comment: @Chenmunka I made a grammatical error but I'm not sure how you're reading it. Is the total amount of heavyweight boxers today X, less than the heavyweight boxers Y at some point in the 1970s?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the statistics but it could be a very definite possibility. I don't know the exact cutoff for the 70s but in the 1920s the heavyweight limit started at 175lbs, and I don't believe cruiserweight was introduced until the late 70s or 80s. So a lot of guys boxing today at light heavy and cruiser would have been heavies back then.